# import zlib error when cross compiling python for arm

Tags: python, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling, zlib

I am compiling python for arm, on my ubuntu in virtual box. After all these steps run and I place the python on the machine with the arm processor. I run the command "python" in the terminal and I get an error that says it can not import zlib. I've been trying many of the solutions online and none have worked for me. Alas, my last hope is trying to post this problem here. I am able to get it working on the target machine when this line:

```
rm -r lib2to3 idlelib lib-tk site-packages config lib-dynload
```

is written like this:

```
rm -r lib2to3 idlelib lib-tk site-packages config lib-dynload distutils
```

I need distutils because I am trying to install pip on the machine. I am unable to though because I believe distutils depends on zlib, but I can't get python to find zlib after cross compiling it for the target machine. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.5.The following are the steps I am taking...

```
mkdir -p pybuild
cd pybuild

# download arm-fsl toolchain
git clone git@github.com:embeddedarm/linux-2.6.35.3-imx28.git

# set path variables
export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/linux-2.6.35.3-imx28/cross-toolchain/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/bin/
export BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH=`pwd`

# sqlite3 headers
wget http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/pool/main/s/sqlite3/libsqlite3-dev_3.7.13-1~bpo60+1_armel.deb
ar vx libsqlite3-dev_3.7.13-1~bpo60+1_armel.deb
tar xzf data.tar.gz
mv usr/* .

# zlib
wget http://www.gzip.org/zlib/zlib-1.1.4.tar.gz
tar xvf zlib-1.1.4.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.1.4
CC=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc \
LDSHARED="arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libz.so.1" \
./configure --shared --prefix=$BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH
make
make install
cd ..

# openssl
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1i.tar.gz
tar xvf openssl-1.0.1i.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1i
./Configure dist --prefix=$BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH
make CC="arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc" AR="arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-ar r" RANLIB="arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-ranlib"
make install
cd ..

# python dependencies
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tgz
tar -xvzf Python-2.7.3.tgz
cd Python-2.7.3

# build for the host system
./configure
make python Parser/pgen
mv python hostpython
mv Parser/pgen Parser/hostpgen
make distclean

# patch it up
wget http://randomsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Python-2.7.3-xcompile.patch
patch -p1 < Python-2.7.3-xcompile.patch

# configure
CC=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc \
CXX=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++ \
AR=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-ar \
RANLIB=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-ranlib \
PYTHON_XCOMPILE_DEPENDENCIES_PREFIX=$BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH \
./configure --host=arm-linux --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=$BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH/tmp

# build
make clean
make HOSTPYTHON=./hostpython \
PYTHON_XCOMPILE_DEPENDENCIES_PREFIX=$BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH \
HOSTPGEN=./Parser/hostpgen \
BLDSHARED="arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared" \
HOSTARCH=arm-linux \
BUILDARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu \
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi- \
CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes | tee make.log 2>&1

# "install"
make install HOSTPYTHON=./hostpython \
BLDSHARED="arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared" \
HOSTARCH=arm-linux \
BUILDARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu \
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi- \
CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes prefix=$BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH/Python-   2.7.3/_install | tee install.log 2>&1

# create a target directory for a minimal version of the installation
cd $BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH/Python-2.7.3/
rm -r _install_minimal
mkdir -p _install_minimal/bin
mkdir -p _install_minimal/usr/lib/python2.7
mkdir -p _install_minimal/usr/include

# copy in the python binary file
cd $BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH/Python-2.7.3/
cp _install/bin/python2.7 _install_minimal/bin/python

# bundle up the lib files into a zip file, after removing unneeded bits
cd $BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH/Python-2.7.3/_install/lib/
rm -r python2.7-minimal
cp -r python2.7 python2.7-minimal
cd python2.7-minimal
rm -r lib2to3 idlelib lib-tk site-packages config lib-dynload
rm *.doc *.txt
rm -r `find -name "test"`
zip -r -y python27.zip .

# copy in the python library files
cd $BASE_PYTHON_COMPILATION_PATH/Python-2.7.3
cp _install/lib/python2.7-minimal/python27.zip _install_minimal/usr/lib/
cp -r _install/lib/python2.7/config _install_minimal/usr/lib/python2.7/
cp -r _install/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload _install_minimal/usr/lib/python2.7/
cp -r _install/lib/python2.7/site-packages _install_minimal/usr/lib/python2.7/
cp -r _install/include/python2.7 _install_minimal/usr/include/
cd _install_minimal
rm ../../python.zip
zip -r ../../python.zip .
cd ../../..

echo "Compilation complete (hopefully successfully). Now, connect to the Sandisk device's wifi hotspot,"
echo "and then run the local ./upload_python.sh script."
```

Comment: Which of those steps is actually copying the cross-compiled `libz.so` over to the target device?

Comment: Sorry just getting back to you. but its actually this `line cp -r _install/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload _install_minimal/usr/lib/python2.7/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was going wrong. I changed

```
rm -r lib2to3 idlelib lib-tk site-packages config lib-dynload
```

to

```
rm -r site-packages config lib-dynload
```

Also, whenever running the build script, be sure to remove the pybuild directory on the beginning of each run. On subsequent runs, with the pybuild directory still existing, it removes the .so files for some reason.